# any_instance is not instance-agnostic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a problem with testing one of my workers in rails app. It looks like this:

```
class UserStatisticsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  def perform(administration_id = nil)
    administrations(administration_id).find_each do |administration|
      User::StatisticsCalculator.new.recalculate_if_needed(administration.id)
    end
  end

  private

  def administrations(administration_id = nil)
    administration_id.present? ? Administration.where(id: administration_id) : Administration.all
  end
end
```

And it is tested with rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserStatisticsWorker do

  describe 'perform' do
    let!(:administration) { create(:administration) }
    let!(:administration_2) { create(:administration) }

    context 'when administration_id is present' do
      it 'runs User::StatisticsCalculator for one administration' do
        expect_any_instance_of(User::StatisticsCalculator).to receive(:recalculate_if_needed).once

        subject.perform(administration.id)
      end
    end

    context 'when administration_id is not present' do
      it 'runs User::StatisticsCalculator for all administrations' do
        expect_any_instance_of(User::StatisticsCalculator).to receive(:recalculate_if_needed).twice

        subject.perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The second spec is not pass with following error:

```
   The message 'recalculate_if_needed' was received by #<User::StatisticsCalculator:85721520 > but has already been received by #<User::StatisticsCalculator:0x0000000a383498>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *very* good practice is to avoid any_instance_of and instead extract private methods in your worker which can be more easily tested. A refactor would look something like this:

```
class UserStatisticsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  def perform(administration_id = nil)
    administrations(administration_id).find_each do |administration|
      recalculate_if_needed(administration)
    end
  end

  private

  def recalculate_if_needed(administration)
    User::StatisticsCalculator.new.recalculate_if_needed(administration.id)
  end

  def administrations(administration_id = nil)
    administration_id.present? ? Administration.where(id: administration_id) : Administration.all
  end
end
```

Then, test it like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserStatisticsWorker do

  describe 'perform' do
    let!(:administration) { create(:administration) }
    let!(:other_administration) { create(:administration) }

    context 'when administration_id is present' do
      it 'tries to recalculate for the specific administration' do
        expect(subject).to receive(:recalculate_if_needed).once

        subject.perform(administration.id)
      end
    end

    context 'when administration_id is not present' do
      it 'tries to recalculate for all administrations' do
        expect(subject).to receive(:recalculate_if_needed).twice

        subject.perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have set the expectation to happen twice on an instance... but what is actually happening is that it is being called Once on two different instances.

ie this is not the expectation that you're looking for...

see the other answer for what you could try instead.